# How to make a new pandas DF column conditionally based on two other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
col 1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5
'abc' |   1  |  20  |  10  |  15
'abc' |   2  |  25  |  5   |  30
'def' |   1  |  340 |  12  |  22
'def' |   2  |  185 |  16  |  120
...
```

I'd like to create another column `col6` which is based on the conditional: if `col2` ==1, then `col3` * `col5`,  otherwise 0; if `col2` == 2 then `col4` * `col5`,  otherwise 0. So the resulting df should look like:

```
col 1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6
'abc' |   1  |  20  |  10  |  15  | 300
'abc' |   2  |  25  |  5   |  30  | 150
'def' |   1  |  340 |  12  |  22  | 7480
'def' |   2  |  185 |  16  |  120 | 1920
...
```

The reason it should return 0 if neither 1 or 2 is just in case `col2` doesn't have a 1 or a 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
df.loc[df['col2'] ==1,'col6']=df['col3']*df['col5']
df.loc[df['col2'] ==2,'col6']=df['col4']*df['col5']
df['col6']=df['col6'].fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
m1 = df.col2 == 1
m2 = df.col2 == 2

df['col6'] = np.select([m1, m2], [df.col3 * df.col5, df.col4 * df.col5], default=0)
print (df)
   col 1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
0  'abc'     1    20    10    15   300
1  'abc'     2    25     5    30   150
2  'def'     1   340    12    22  7480
3  'def'     2   185    16   120  1920
```

Comment: I tried this but it's bringing back `0.0` for all of `col6`. I took out `default=0` and I still get 0

Comment: @jceg316 - are data numeric? What return `df.col2.dtype` ?

Comment: `dtype('int64')`

Comment: @jceg316 - Is not here multiple by zero? E.g. in col5 in real data?

Comment: it's real data in all columns, no zeros and `col3` `col4` `col5` are all float64

Comment: @jceg316 - so if check `print(m1)` and `print (m2)` it working correctly? Because it should working.